# Javascript maths not working

Tags: javascript

Here is my Javascript:

```
var total = $(this).text();
var calc = total * 100;
var paid = calc * 0.333;
```

The HTML is simple:

```
<div class="price"><span>£0.21</span></div>
```

How can I remove the '£' char from the string so I can do the maths?

Answer (score 4):

This will remove all characters from the string that are not a number or decimal point.

```
var total = $(this).text().replace(/[^\d.]/g,'');
var calc = total * 100;
var paid = calc * 0.333;
```

Useful if there are any comma separators as well.

The `*` will take care of the conversion from String. If you want something more explicit, you can use the unary `+` operator.

```
var total = +($(this).text().replace(/[^\d.]/g,'')); // <-- has + at beginning
var calc = total * 100;
var paid = calc * 0.333;
```

Comment: That allows for very free input, which can result in errors. If the span contains 2 $ 78cow89 it will still convert to a 'valid' float, which is probably not desired.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Alright, but if the span contains `2 $ 78cow89`, then can we really know the desired value? I'm guessing the span doesn't contain arbitrary data.

Comment: So is there something in this answer *really* worth downvoting? Or is someone just being spiteful?

Comment: If you just strip the one expected currency symbol, the rest would be convertable to float. If it can't, parseFloat will cause an error, which is probably better than calculating using the wrong value. If you want to, you could perform additional checks.

Comment: @GolezTrol: *"...parseFloat will cause an error"* You sure about that? Take your example string above, start it with the currency symbol, so you have `'£2 $ 78cow89'`. Then strip the first character, and call `parseFloat()`. Does it give an error? No, because `parseFloat` will honor a string that begins with a number (or spaces then a number). It just strips away everything after the number. [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/WArsA/)

Comment: ...at some point there needs to be some assurance of the structure of the content being processed. If we can't have that assurance, then we can't have a useful application.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I'd vote for a more precise checking of the value instead of just stripping all non numeric characters. I'd go as far as to say that it is wrong to do that, because there is no validation and debugging (or more precise, concluding there is an error at all) is harder. Especially when your input is a generated html page, you need all the validation you can get, because you never know when any step in the generation of that input can go wrong.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I suppose I could see the client browser as a very small safety net, but validation matters should really be buttoned up tight on the server. I'd concede that it would be an improvement to my answer to strip out only those characters that are expected from the server, like currency symbol, comma separator and perhaps white space. Overall, I'd rather see a semi-redundant custom attribute used in place of modifying decorated text content.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) the string to remove the '£':

```
var total = $(this).text().slice(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always have a '£' sign at the beginning of your string, you can use a substring before assigning total (which will cast from string to number, correctly this time).

You can also rely on a regular expression such as

```
/[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*/
```

Cheers,

-stan

Answer (score 1):

1. use [slice()](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/string.htm#slice), [substr()](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/string.htm#substr) or [substring()](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/string.htm#substring) to cut out the part you need
2. use [parseFloeat()](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/unabhaengig.htm#parse_float) or [parseInt()](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/unabhaengig.htm#parse_int) before doing calculations with your number to be sure it *is* a number

Comment: jQuery's `.slice()` is meant specifically for jQuery objects. You're looking for `String.slice()`.

Answer (score 0):

check out the [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/parseFloat) function.

Edit: whoops, i meant to write parseFloat; couple bits of difference.

Comment: parseFloat/Int will fail because of the £.

Comment: parseFloat will indeed fail on this input.

Comment: yea, just looked up the reference, and it only removes trailing chars, not prefixed symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Use SubStr to copy from the second character (#1). Use parseFloat to convert to float.

```
var total = $(this).text().substr(1).parseFloat();
var calc = total * 100;
var paid = calc * 0.333;
```

Comment: That isn't the proper use of `parseFloat()`. You need to send the string to be parsed as an argument to the method instead of chaining it. (Unless you were to extend `String.prototype` with a method.)

Answer (score 0):

parseint is wrong.. it would be parsefloat...

but you need to strip the first char before you parsefloat otherwise it will return NaN (not a number)

```
var total = "£0.21";
total = total.substring(1);
total = parseFloat(total);
var calc = total * 100; 
var paid = calc * 0.333; 
alert(paid);
```